# Counting of edges coloring in a graph

Tags: group-theory, coloring

[image]

The problem is to count of coloring graphs. We have three colors.

And I found all automorphisms.

It is:
$$\alpha_1: (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)$$
$$\alpha_2: (123456) $$
$$\alpha_3: (135)(246) $$
$$\alpha_4: (14)(25)(36) $$
$$\alpha_5: (153)(426) $$
$$\alpha_6: (165432) $$
I have no idea how to solve it. It's very important for me to understand it.
I understand Burnside lemma. For example I can count of nodes coloring, but when it comes to edges I got into trouble.

Comment: I think you should recheck those automorphisms.

Comment: Any automorphism would need to fix $2$ and $6$, so the automorphism group is generated by $(15)$ and $(34)$, giving us the group $V_4=C_2\times C_2$. Your list is wrong. The fact that you're mentioning graph automorphisms and Burnside's lemma at all implies you're counting edge colorings **modulo group actions**. Are you counting modulo only graph automorphisms, or permutations of the colors as well? You absolutely need to tell us what the actual question is - how are we supposed to help you answer your question if you won't tell us what it is precisely?'

Comment: I made a mistake. Obviously we have 4 automorpihsms
$(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6); (34)(1)(2)(5)(6); (15)(2)(3)(4)(6); (15)(6)(2)(4)(34)$   I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: What about my comment don't you understand? You say you're counting edge colorings, but if that were true then automorphisms and Burnside's lemma would be totally irrelevant. So you must be counting orbits (of edge colorings) under some group action - are you counting modulo graph automorphisms only? You haven't clarified for us what the real problem is yet.